# Kubernetes Rest API - Exec (re)size

Tags: kubernetes

How can I set Size (ie: cols and rows) using Rest API WebSockets Exec? API doc does not mention it.

`kubectl exec -v=99` doesn't give me a clue how it's setting size.

I've read some people setting environment variables COLUMNS and ROWS when running `kubectl exec -it $container env COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES TERM=$TERM bash`, but there is nothing documented  for exec method api in order to set variables either.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: You have to send those envs mentioned in my question as multiple command's in your query.

ie: to Execute bash with 80 columns and 24 rows:
`&command=env&command=COLUMNS%3D80&command=ROWS%3D24&command=/bin/bash`